# AVR timer output when Data Direction Register set to input

Tags: microcontroller, avr, timer, output

This question refers specifically to an ATmega328P, but probably can be generalized to most or all AVR MCUs.

Known 1:  When the Data Direction Register (DDR) for a pin is set as input mode, it is still possible to write to the PORT for that pin; instead of producing an output, the value written to PORT will just change the pin between pullup and tri-state mode.

Known 2: A pin can be configured to toggle its output state along with the waveform generation module in a timer.

**Question**: When the DDR for a pin is configured as *input*, and that same pin is also configured to change state along with a *timer*, will the timer waveform effectively just rapidly switch the pin between tri-state and pullup modes? Or will the pin behave more reasonably, staying in tri-state/pullup according to the PORT value?

I guess the question could be restated as: Does the timer write to the PORT register in order to change the pin's state?

The only thing remotely relevant I could find in the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf#page=138&zoom=auto,-109,679) is the following line:

> ...However, note that the Data Direction Register (DDR) bit corresponding to the [timer] pin must be set in order to enable the output driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "I/O-Ports" section of each AVR datasheet gives a detailed treatment of what each "virtual" output affects. In the case of `OCnx`, PVOV is directly affected, and PVOV is defined as "Port Value Override Value - If PVOE is set, the port value is set to PVOV, regardless of the setting of the PORTxn Register bit.". PVOE is set to `OCnx ENABLE`, controlled by `COMnx`. Therefore the `OCnx` value is *not* written to `PORTx`, and will *always* be output on the pin with an appropriate value in `DDRx` regardless of the setting of `PORTx`.

Comment: Thank you. That makes good sense, and I see that in the block diagram in the I/O section of the datasheet. Are you saying that setting COMnx to the right value(s) will cause the timer to directly drive PVOV?

Comment: `OCnx` drives PVOV directly, and `COMnx` drives PVOE indirectly.